# Installation of older version of docker using apt

Tags: apt, 18.04, docker

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.
I need to install `docker 17.03.2-ce`

Using `apt install docker.io` resolves in installing version 18.06.1-ce.

Using `apt install docker.io=17.03.2~ce` prints:

```
Version '17.03.2~ce' for 'docker.io' was not found
```

How to install docker in version 17.03.2-ce?

Comment: the `docker.io` package of 17.03.2 version available on [Launchpad-site](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/docker.io/17.03.2-0ubuntu5)

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri I'm preparing a script so I prefer installation using command line (for example by using apt)

Comment: If that's relevant, then you should edit it into the question, not bury it in the comments. Apt can only download from repositories that it knows about. There is no known repository with the version you seek. Yes, you can script it, the download is simply an additional action (wget) outside of apt.

Comment: @hohdoee You're limited to the versions of `docker.io` listed in the output of `apt-cache policy docker.io`.  If the version you are after is not listed there, then you can't install that version via apt-get and would be restricted to downloading the older version manually and then installing it.